# PrintWriter in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

The code below sends "ping" to my localhost server in java, how would I do the same thing in JavaScript?

```
new PrintWriter(new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9002).getOutputStream(), true).println("ping");
```

I ran it in javaScript and it said:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: PrintWriter is not defined

Comment: just to clarify, what exactly is the code you ran in Javascript? how you ran it (in browser console?)?

Comment: A Chrome Extension Where you can put javascript on any page. I ran the exact same code I pasted above for java in JavaScript https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-javascript-for-web/poakhlngfciodnhlhhgnaaelnpjljija

Comment: hope you understand that Java and Javascript are entirely different languages and the only thing common is the similarity in name... forgive me if you already know..

Comment: I know, but some thinks like if statements work in both :P I taught i'd try it, So what i'm asking here is: How would I send a message to a server using JavaScript?

Comment: PrintWriter is a java specific class, you dont have a function or class in javascript with same name. Also I think it wouldn't be easy to achieve this functionality using javascript.

Comment: To send message/data to server from javascript you have to use ajax requests. http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: that error tells me you have tried literally nothing but copy and paste the same code into a javascript engine. Figure out what it does, attempt to replicate it in javascript, and if you still cant figure it out, **THEN** come ask a question.

Comment: http://html5doctor.com/methods-of-communication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java and JavaScript are two **entirely-different** languages. The similarity in names is due to an unfortunate PR decision in the 90's on Netscape's part. You can't expect Java code to "just work" in JavaScript for a multitude of reasons; it's like expecting COBOL code to be compiled and understood by a C compiler.

The standard way to send a "ping" to a server is to use [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). Keep in mind though, that there is a same-origin-policy restriction. What this means is that you can only make requests to resources on the *same* subdomain.

There are a few ways around this; take a look at the following answer for details:

- [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)